# four buttons and a bunch of conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an mvc app where I have 4 buttons on my web page. I need to enable/disable each button based on a workflow of a bunch of different conditions. What's the best way to manage this? Right now, there's almost 30 conditions and counting.

Not really looking for a specific solution as much as a thought process or an approach to keep it simple.

Thanks,
rod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create different *partial views* for each *scenario*, not each button set.

This way, you can manage the views based on your business requirement.

In your main ViewModel, store the "scenario", not "flags for each button".

E.g:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    viewModel.ScenarioName = "Scenario1";
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Then if your "ScenarioName" matches the partial view name, you can simply do this:

```
<%: RenderPartial(Model.ScenarioName, Model.SomethingYouNeedForPartial) %>
```

That way your controller/viewmodel stays really clean.

Of course, this all depends on your "conditions" and business rules.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about your situation (like whether these are known conditions, or if the conditions are based on actions by the user), this is where I would start:

I would start with a ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public bool ShowButton1 {get; set;}
    public bool ShowButton2 {get; set;}
    public bool ShowButton3 {get; set;}
    public bool ShowButton4 {get; set;}
}
```

And put the logic for the conditions in your controllers:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    viewModel.ShowButton1 = condition1 && condition2;
    viewModel.ShowButton2 = condition3 && condition4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WPF uses Commands, which allow you to assign a CanExecute event to each command.  Heaps more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx.

I'd avoid using a single large function with many nested conditionals, as these become impossible to read.

Comment: I'm not sure WPF would help with a MVC site.